# SQL set to zero after subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am writing a script to subtract from a column, and set it to zero if the result is less than 0.
So far, I have

```
UPDATE [table01] SET [c1] = [c1] - ? WHERE [id] = ?
UPDATE [table01] SET [c1] = 0 WHERE [id] = ? AND [c1] < 0
```

Is there any way to shorten the above so that it subtracts and then sets to 0 if the column is less than 0, rather than span it across two `UPDATE` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the SQL you shared, this seems to be MS SQL-Server, which, unfortunately, doesn't have a `least` function. You could, however, still achieve the same behavior with a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE [table01] 
SET    [c1] = CASE WHEN [c1] > ? THEN [c1] - ? -- Both ?s set with the same value
                   ELSE 0
              END
WHERE  [id] = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` statement.  Same result as other answer, just rearranged the logic

```
UPDATE [table01] 
SET [c1] = CASE WHEN [c1] - ? < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [c1] - ? END
WHERE [id] = ?
```